# how to launch eclipse: eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate in windows xp?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate shared lib in windows xp OS..I keep getting this error when i launch eclipse  and i browsed through but not able to find any correct solution . can anyone help me out i really in the need of eclipse right now?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Java JRE/JDK ? Otherwise a more detailed error message would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What got it all working for me was to download eclipse indigo 3.7.2 and (this is very important) EXTRACT IT DIRECTLY INTO MY PROGRAMS FOLDER. Before I would extract it to my desktop and copy into the programs folder (C:\Program Files) but I would jus get an error message saying "The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library" when trying to run eclipse.

After extracting eclipse directly to my programs folder I ran it and so far all is working well :)